# Is Yoast SEO plugin the reason my Facebook share button isn't grabbing the fallback image?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, share

I noticed in the WordPress plugin support forum for Yoast SEO that someone else seems to be having the same problem. I'm not sure what's causing it for sure, though, or how to resolve it.

A few days ago I launched my website; [(the link is here)](http://www.moosenotes.com). As of today I only have one blog post, and it doesn't contain an image. So in the Yoast SEO plugin, in the social tab for Facebook, I added a fallback image of a male moose. It was working just fine.

Then I changed the image to a female moose, cleared caches and used the Facebook debugger to clear that, too. And now all I get is a white box where the image should go. I've tried everything and can't figure out what's causing the problem. No one responds to support requests in the plugin forum on WordPress, so I thought I'd come here and see if anyone has some suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: I just thought to check and see if I can share my homepage on Facebook. When I type in the URL in a new post on Facebook, it immediately grabs the correct image and the site description. So that's working just fine. It's the fallback image for posts that don't have an image that's not working.

Comment: I removed this second followup comment. It no longer applies.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? This is normally due to cache problems. My recommendation when you change the image of a URL that has already been scraped by Facebook is to change the og tags of your site and use a total different name for the image. In your case, if your image was mysite.com/mouse.jpg, you should change it to something like mysite.com/mouse2.jpg, otherwise, FB crawler may don't see the change and your data might remain inconsistent.

Comment: Thank you, this is a really great suggestion!